# How to use the brotli npm module to compress files

Tags: node.js, npm, compression, brotli

I would like to use [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli) to compress files, but I'm a bit stuck by the documention.

In a linux shell :

```
npm install brotli # npm@4.1.2 # brotli@1.3.1 

node # v6.9.4
```

Then inside node:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var brotli = require('brotli');

brotli.compress(fs.readFileSync('myfile.txt')); // output is numbers

fs.writeFile('myfile.txt.br', brotli.compress(fs.readFileSync('bin.tar')), function(err){ if (!err) { console.log('It works!');}});
"It works!"
```

But the file is full of numbers too...

I've never used streams and fs like that in node, can someone explains how to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? If the file looks something like <Buffer 00 02 45> it is correct as you are compressing the buffer that returns from `fs.readFileSync('myfile.txt')` and writing it to another file.
If you want to see the decoded buffer you need to decompress it before writing to disk

Comment: I have to compress files with node (and use the brotli compression as it's cool :) ). In a shell I would have used the "bro" command from the compiled project, but here I don't have access to it.

Comment: if you don't specify an encoding type, node.js will use utf-8 by default. Not sure if this would work but try using binary instead.
`fs.writeFile('myfile.txt.br', brotli.compress(fs.readFileSync('bin.tar')), 'binary', function(err){ if (!err) { console.log('It works!');}});`

Comment: The problem was indeed that I did'nt put any settings/encoding type like `'binary'` or the object in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this simple JS code you are compressing each `*.html` `*.css` `*.js` file inside the folder you choose (in this case `/dist`)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const compress = require('brotli/compress');

const brotliSettings = {
    extension: 'br',
    skipLarger: true,
    mode: 1, // 0 = generic, 1 = text, 2 = font (WOFF2)
    quality: 10, // 0 - 11,
    lgwin: 12 // default
};

fs.readdirSync('dist/').forEach(file => {
    if (file.endsWith('.js') || file.endsWith('.css') || file.endsWith('.html')) {
        const result = compress(fs.readFileSync('dist/' + file), brotliSettings);
        fs.writeFileSync('dist/' + file + '.br', result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But there is a typo in your import, either write `const brotli = require('brotli');` (line 2) or remove the `brotli.` (line 14).